# pgr_createTopology() 'Connection to the server has been lost'

Tags: pgrouting, pgadmin-4

When trying to create topology from pgAdmin 4 (version 2.1) with the `pgr_createTopology` function I get an error:

"Connection to the server has been lost."

The database is on localhost. The input network data set contains 865609 road features from Open Street Map.

When executing the query it starts running and shows the messages such as '1000 edges processed', indicating that the initial function execution is correct. Since the data set is rather large I do not look (on the monitor) at the entire process. But three times now when I came back I saw the error.

[Connection error](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/connect_error.html) in the pgAdmin documentation only provides explanation about initializing the connection. That does not seem to be the problem as query execution starts normally.

I have previously tried with smaller datasets with succes, so my guess is that the size/processing time is the culprit here.

How can I prevent the 'connection to the server has been lost' error from showing up when executing the pgr_createTopology() function?

Version info:
POSTGIS="2.4.3 r16312" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" RASTER

Comment: I get the same error. I will try with a subset and come back.

Comment: For now a workaround seems to be to batch process. This does not however, solve the problem.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270780/pgr-createtopology-with-large-datasets/277161#277161